# Access all the fields in ROS msg

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a very simple and stupid question, but I searched everywhere, and maybe because it's so simple I can't find an answer.

I created a msg like this (and maybe Im gonna add a string later as well)

```
int64 intensity 
int64 location
int64 duration
```

And now I'm trying to give values to each of this variables and publish them in a topic.
I did the follow:

```
// (dont know how I'll do if I had the string, but thats not the problem **yet**)
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Int64>("chatter", 1000);
std_msgs::Int64 msg;
```

Now the question comes here. In the ros publisher tutorials, we use msg.data, and as I searched online I found that data was the name of our variable. However, I did not understand that. How can I give values to every field of my message? I thought on doing something like this, but I know its not correct...

```
msg.data.intensity = 15;
msg.data.location = 100;
msg.data.duration = 37;

//ROS_INFO("intensity %d, local %d, dura %d ", msg.data.intensity,msg.data, msg.data);
chatter_pub.publish(msg);
```

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257620/access-all-the-fields-in-ros-msg/) by [jonagf](https://answers.ros.org/users/29777/jonagf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you created a custom message then you need to create a Publisher that uses that custom message type. Right now your publisher is using a [`std_msgs/Int64`](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int64.html) type which only has a single field named `data`.

Let's say your custom message is in a package called `my_custom_msgs` and that the file is named `Custom.msg`. Then you would need to declare your publisher like

```
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros:Publisher pub = n.advertise<my_custom_msgs::Custom>("chatter", 1000);
```

Now you can declare a message using the custom data type, populate each of the fields in your message, and publish.

```
my_custom_msgs::Custom msg;
msg.intensity = 15;
msg.location = 100;
msg.duration = 37;
pub.publish(msg);
```

Later, if you change your message to include a string so that it becomes

```
int64 intensity 
int64 location
int64 duration
string note
```

Then you will create the publisher the same way, but populating the fields and publishing will be

```
my_custom_msgs::Custom msg;
msg.intensity = 15;
msg.location = 100;
msg.duration = 37;
msg.note = "Hello";
pub.publish(msg);
```

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2017-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jonagf](https://answers.ros.org/users/29777/jonagf/) on 2017-03-22**:
Thank you very much! It was very useful! The package part was missing in my head, now it makes sense!